# "No bluetooth adapters found" for my Easynote LS

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth

Easynote LS Laptop with Ubuntu 16.04.

I get the following error:

> No bluetooth adapters found

Running:

```
rfkill list
```

Result with:

```
0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I have read other threads with this problem but they all seem to be about Dell or HP or other devices

What should I do?

Edit: added results of *lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'*

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 064e:c21c Suyin Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: Easynotes have a physical switch for Bluetooth (FN+F3 or FN+F& or...). Make sure you turn it on and try again.

Comment: Edit the question to include results for `lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

Comment: @MichaelBay, there is no "physical" switch for BT (Fn or non-Fn) on Easynote LS.

Comment: @Jeremy31  Done.

Comment: I don't think your computer has a bluetooth chipset

Comment: Oh... OK. You said you don't think tho (how do I make sure it definitely doesn't?